Blackscreen on screenshot
I just notice that video streaming websites, such as Max and Disney Plus, can blackout their video when I activate screenshot application or when I want to share screen in Zoom. What technique is used to implement this effect? How can web pages inside a browser detect screenshot application is activated, isn't it breaking the browser sandbox? And, can this be used to prevent image/text screenshot?

(1) What is "Max"? Do you have links to the websites you are talking about? (2) "when I activate screenshot application" is that grabbing app running on Windows OS or MacOS? (3) "Isn't it breaking the browser sandbox?" Not if the browser or OS supports such encryption and/or DRM protection. Clearly your operating system is stopping the screenshot app. Browsers (as a native app) also can detect keypresses (eg: when doing "ESC" from fullscreen) so they can detect a keyboard shortcut to screengrab. Need more info about steps on how to recreate the problem you see.

(1) Max is the rebranded HBO streaming service, which is quite popular.  (2) It doesn't matter if you are using what OS, I tried Windows and iPhone, both the same. (3) this is what I want to know: either the OS knows a streaming is playing in the browser, or the browser knows screenshot is activated, which one is true?


What technique is used to implement this effect?

DRM.

How can web pages inside a browser detect screenshot application is activated, isn't it breaking the browser sandbox?

Neither web pages, nor the browser, detect when a screenshot or recording is happening.  The browser isn't actually doing the rendering of the video.  The video is encrypted, and its rendering is done further down the pipe at a lower layer.  Different techniques can be used, some of which where the video isn't even decrypted until it hits the display device.

And, can this be used to prevent image/text screenshot?

Not directly.  You'd have to render that content into video, and encrypt that video.  This is expensive, a real hassle, and doesn't provide as much protection as you might think.  That's why it's only done for protecting expensive high resolution commercial video content.

Appreciate your response, but can you briefly explain why and how the video become black when screenshot app is activated? There got to be some interaction between the OS and the browser..

@SamTest The screen was always black,.  The video wasn't on the screen at the layer where the screen capture could be taken.  The browser and the regular graphics layer just see black.  They don't know what the pixels are for the encrypted video.  The video is stitched on-top later on at a lower layer.
